# unable to include PHPMailer in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, phpmailer

we have the code to send mails using `PHPMailer` by including the `PHPMailerAutoload.php` file in our php files like..

```
require "PHPMailerAutoload.php";
```

and then

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

but this syntax is not acceptable in zend framework2 files, it says as "Fatal error" with "Class not found".
I've tried to move the `PHPMailer` to library folder of zf2 & then to include them by use `Lib\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload`which is zf2 standard way of including any library files,
but even this doesn't work.

Did anyone work on this kind, please help me

Lib folder is not there in zend framework 2 but I've added in vendor & used it as

[image]

`use Lib\folder\file;`

which really works, also coming to the error..it is.,

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Lib\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload' not found in 
<b>/var/www/html/sample.php</b> on line 
<b>503</b>
<br />
```

Comment: ZF2 doesn't have a 'library folder' so I'm not sure what you mean by that. Really you want to install PHPMailer using composer, then you don't have to worry about autoloading. As for the fatal error - please add the full error message to your question. It's almost certainly a simple namespace issue.

Comment: +1 for using composer instead. I think [this](https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer) is it on packagist.

Answer (score 3):

It's rarely a good idea to add or edit stuff in `vendor/` - let Composer manage this folder. As per my comment I'd suggest you install PHPMailer using composer instead, just add:

```
"phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2",
```

to the 'require' section of your `composer.json` and then run `composer install`. This is also the suggested installation method in [PHPMailer's README](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master).

The error you added to your question relates to PHP not finding the autoload include file. If you switch to Composer you don't need this file at all so you can just remove your require line.

It's likely that to instantiate the class you'd need to use:

```
$mail = new \PHPMailer;
```

(note the backslash), as ZF2 classes usually declare a namespace at the start. The backslash tells PHP that it should grab the PHPMailer class from the global namespace.